# Core Data Memory Crash

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using Core Data for the first time in my project and I feel there is a serious problem in my approach. What I am doing is that I fetch data from server (data includes pngs as well). Save it in core data locally. Then at app launch, I load the entire data in an array. Then this array is used where ever I need it. I think I am following a very bad approach. Can anyone guide me what should be a better approach? Should I only query Core Data when data is needed instead of loading everything in memory at start?

When data is being populated to the array, I can see memory increasing in Xcode and after a certain value, it crashes.

Here is my code for saving data:

```
func saveDataLocally () {

    let moContext = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "FoodPlace", in: moContext)

    for foodPlaceData in self.downloadedData_ {
        let foodPlace = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: moContext) as! FoodPlace
        foodPlace.objectId = foodPlaceData.objectId_
        foodPlace.name = foodPlaceData.name_
        foodPlace.address = foodPlaceData.address_
        foodPlace.keywords = foodPlaceData.keywords_
        foodPlace.baseFavourites = Int64(foodPlaceData.baseFavourites_)
        foodPlace.startingTime = foodPlaceData.startingTime_
        foodPlace.endingTime = foodPlaceData.endingTime_
        foodPlace.category = foodPlaceData.category_
        foodPlace.basePrice = foodPlaceData.basePrice_
        foodPlace.dealTitle = foodPlaceData.dealTitle_
        foodPlace.versionNumber = Int64(foodPlaceData.versionNumber_)
        foodPlace.menuItems = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: foodPlaceData.menuItems_)
        foodPlace.location = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: foodPlaceData.location_)
        foodPlace.deals = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: foodPlaceData.deals_)
        foodPlace.foodPlacePhotos = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: foodPlaceData.foodPlacePhotos_)

        moContext.insert(foodPlace)
    }

    do {
        try moContext.save()
    }
    catch let error {
        print("error saving = \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

where `menuItems` is a `Dictionary` which contains text as well as png images. Also, `deals` and `foodPlacePhotos` only contain png images.

Here is the code for fetching:

```
func loadDataLocally () {
    let moContext = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FoodPlace")

    do {
        let results = try moContext.fetch(request)
        let savedFoodPlaceData = results as! [FoodPlace]

        downloadedData_ = []

        for foodPlace in savedFoodPlaceData {
            let objectId = foodPlace.objectId
            let name = foodPlace.name
            let address = foodPlace.address
            let keywords = foodPlace.keywords
            let baseFavourites = foodPlace.baseFavourites
            let startingTime = foodPlace.startingTime
            let endingTime = foodPlace.endingTime
            let category = foodPlace.category
            let menuItems = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: foodPlace.menuItems!) as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
            let location = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: foodPlace.location!) as? Dictionary<String,Double>
            let deals = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: foodPlace.deals!) as? [UIImage]
            let basePrice = Float(foodPlace.basePrice)
            let dealTitle = foodPlace.dealTitle
            let versionNumber = foodPlace.versionNumber
            let foodPlacePhotos = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: foodPlace.foodPlacePhotos!) as? [UIImage]

            let data = FoodPlaceData(objectId: objectId!, name: name!, address: address!, category: category!, keywords: keywords!, baseFavourites: Int(baseFavourites), startingTime: startingTime!, endingTime: endingTime!, menuItems: menuItems!, location: location!, deals: deals!,basePrice: basePrice,dealTitle: dealTitle!,versionNumber: Int(versionNumber),foodPlacePhotos: foodPlacePhotos!)

            downloadedData_.insert(data, at: downloadedData_.count)
        }
    }
    catch let error {
        print("error fetching = \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

and here is the code for deleting data:

```
func deleteAllLocalData () {
    let moContext = ((UIApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "FoodPlace")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try moContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for managedObject in results {
            let managedObjectData : NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
            moContext.delete(managedObjectData)
        }

        try moContext.save()

    } catch let error {
        print("Delete all data in FoodPlace error : \(error) \((error as NSError).userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use core data multithreading. Please go through https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-concurrency--cms-25118

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't think this is my problem. I am having memory issue that its taking too much of memory and crashes because it gets out of memory. I can see the memory increase and beyond a certain limit, it crashes.

Comment: what is Data amount? I you are facing memory issue then it's also a part of thread management. By the way look into these  https://github.com/mmorey/MDMHPCoreData
 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7C6euzQt-o

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to be prescriptive without a lot more detail about your code.  But a few thoughts:

- rather than storing the PNG data in CoreData itself, consider storing it in the file system directly, and using CoreData to store only the filename for the PNG.
- Alternatively, if you really want the PNGs in CoreData, consider adding a separate entity for the PNG, and adding a one-one relationship from your current entity to the new one.

Either of the above will avoid all the PNG data being loaded into memory when you load the array.  You can then load/unload the PNGs (either from the file system or from the related entity) as needed.

In addition, consider using:

- [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) and/or
- [fetchBatchSize](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506558-fetchbatchsize)

These will help to avoid all the objects being loaded into memory.

Comment: I have added the code.